# Profiling early boot boot

Tags: time, profiling, freebsd, boot

What timekeeping functions should I use if I want to profile the early boot process?

I want to see which drivers take too long to probe/attach/initialize and if there is a way to reduce that amount of time.  There may even be earlier parts of boot which are too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernel tracing can e.g. be done with [ktr(4)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ktr&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).

Another option is to use [dtrace](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/dtrace-using.html). Sample scripts for monitoring the kernel can be found in `/usr/src/cddl/contrib/dtracetoolkit/Kernel/`.